# Load image from nodejs api url into uiimageview

Tags: ios, xcode, node.js, swift, uiimageview

I've ran into this problem where if I try to use "localhost:3000/photo" as my url for the imageview in xcode I don't get an image, but if I use a url where it doesn't url rewrite like "www.somesite.com/image.png" then the image shows up. I believe it might be the way I'm saving to serving the image in node. When I hit my intended url (localhost:3000/photo) the correct image appears on the page. I feel like it should download if I'm serving it right. Let me know what you  think.

```
var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: tableImages[indexPath.row])!
let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
    request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
    completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
})
```

Node

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router(); 
var util = require("util"); 
var fs = require("fs"); 

router.get('/', function(req, res) { 

  res.sendfile("./upload/d0a73ef5f25219955ae8c480a2bbd6dc.jpg");
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

I'm using multer to save

```
app.use(multer({dest: "./upload/"}));
```

My uploading route

```
router.post("/upload", function(req, res, next){ 
    if (req.files) { 
        console.log(util.inspect(req.files));
        if (req.files.myFile.size === 0) {
            return next(new Error("No file selected"));
        }
        fs.exists(req.files.myFile.path, function(exists) { 
            if(exists) { 
                res.end("file"); 
            } else { 
                res.end("no file"); 
            } 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

Here are some screen shots while debugging 
[image]
[image]

Comment: You for sure should get something back. either image or error. In your case likely error. Can you provide what error was returned by NSURLConnection call?

Comment: @NikitaLeonov no errors that I can see. I edited the question with screenshots.

Comment: There was no error because I had the url as /upload not /photo
Everything is working as it should haha dumb mistake.

Comment: :) nice. Good luck further